# Magento 1.4.1.1 Catalogue Price Rules not staying applied

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have an install of Magento 1.4.1.1 that uses catalogue prices rules for different user groups.

Unfortunately the rules do not stay applied after 2-3 days.

I have done the following fix, as described in:
http://mandagreen.com/fixing-catalog-price-rules-cart-issue-in-magento-1-4-1-0/

That stopped the rules from showing up in the catalogue.

Changing line 105 of:

app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php

to:

```
    $gId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Which has helped the rules to be shown when the user with a certain Customer Group has logged in.

However the rule doesn't stay applied for more that 2-3 days. Unless I go into the admin, go to Catalogue Price Rules and click "Apply All"

I've also set up cron jobs on my server for:

```
cron.sh
cron.php
indexer.php
```

How do I create a Cron Job to specifically Apply All the Catalogue Price Rules?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't ever, ever edit the core code.

If your rules aren't staying applied, there's something cron-y going on. Cron is required for Catalog price rules so make sure it's set up properly like so:

```
*/5 * * * * /absolute/path/to/bin/php -f /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, I guess you could write a module to cron some additional code every so often, but you shouldn't have to be doing this if cron is enabled correctly.

If you do want to go down that road, crons are pretty straightforward in Magento

Create a module. If you don't know how to do that, [Start here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) and work your way through.

Then, create an observer file: {{namespace}}/{{modulename}}/Model/Observer.php

Inside that file:

```
<?php

class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer {

  public function functionName() {
      // apply catalog price rules code here
  }

}
```

In your module’s etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
  ...
  <crontab>
    <jobs>
      <unique_cron_job_name>
        <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>{{modulename}}/observer::functionName</model></run>
      </unique_cron_job_name>
    </jobs>
  </crontab>
  ...
</config>
```

Comment: Ah yes, Sorry it did actually create a local Observer.php and not edit the core code.

I have created Cron's for magento/cron.php however I am awaiting a few days to see whether the problem still arises.